# How to register an action to a mouse click when button is selected?

Tags: java

I'm creating a program that allows users to graph vertices and connect them by edges.

One of the buttons is "Add Vertex"
I want this button to be the only button that allows the user to create a vertex by clicking on the canvas. The same logic goes for the rest of the buttons.

I know I need to use mouselistener and/or actionlistener but I don't know how to set the permissions so that the user can't just click anywhere and draw.

All the questions and articles I've read on this only show me how to make a button do a particular action but I want this button, and only this button, to allow a user to do this particular action themselves.

Any references to questions similar to this or articles that address this would be extremely helpful. Thank you

Comment: So you having a drawing area and a button. When the button has been pressed you can click on the drawing area and add a vertex. Otherwise your click does nothing. Did I get that right?

Comment: It would be helpful to include the program that you created so we can use it as a reference.

Comment: Exactly. My canvas is there but I only want users to be able to draw a vertex when this button has been clicked on.

Comment: Then you have to write code that keeps track of "state". And then your action listeners / mouse listeners do different things based on that state.

Comment: Then I would have the button set a boolean flag, then in your mouse listener check the flag. If false, don’t draw. If true, draw and set flag to false. I can write some pseudo code if thats unclear.

Comment: Is there a name for the action that I'm referring to? Would be helpful to read something on it if there exists such a thing.

Comment: pseudo code would be super helpful. But I do understand what you're getting at now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to keep track of whether or not you should draw on the canvas, so define a boolean instance field

```
private boolean shouldDraw;
```

Now in your button handler, when the button is clicked

```
shouldDraw = true
```

Then in your mouse listener, when the mouse is clicked you can check for the flag

```
if(shouldDraw)
{
    shouldDraw = false;
    //do necessary work to draw
}
```

Comment: Understood. I'll try to implement this. Thank you.